# Why am I receiving an uncaught type error in my ES6 code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

fairly new to ES6, and trying to figure out what I've overlooked in this particular example.

I have a form containing a *button* with the *ID* of `#submitBtn`, which I'm trying to add an `eventListener` to, so that when I click on the submit button, I get an alert message - simple, right?

This is what I have so far:

```
class schedule {
    constructor() {
        this.submitBtn = document.querySelector("#submitBtn");
        this.sayHello();
    }

    sayHello() {
        this.submitBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            alert("Hello!");
        })
    }
}

export default schedule;
```

When I check my console, I get an error message that reads:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

If someone could explain to me what I'm missing or overlooking, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Is it possible your constructor is running before the dom is fully initialized? Your query selector is returning a null object, which means it couldn't find anything.

Comment: Can you post all of the code, including the HTML element you’re trying to access in the constructor?

Comment: You'll need to show us your DOM and where/when you are calling `new schedule`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response guys! As @Dr_Derp mentioned, my function was being loaded before the rest of my page. I changed the position of the new schedule like Bergi suggested, and voila! Thanks guys!